# Need some advise about Microsoft flow leader Board

Tags: power-automate

I setting a flow to display leader board in excel file with a list of KPIs
in my tab Performance i wan to show detail KPIs in percentage
but it only show type number (Ex: 100% = 0.1)
In my flow i use concat function to display a variable that i had initialize in flow.
How i can show list of KPIs in my excel file as percentage using concat. I cant initialize each of KPIs in excel in flow because it make my flow run slowly.
Any ideal for this.
Thanks u guys so much

I used the following to show as percentage

```
concat(string(mul(float(body('Parse_JSON')?['Score']),100)),'%')
```

Sample Screenshot below:

[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: Don't use concat. Instead, just put the actual value in the cell, and format the cell as a percentage. Excel will do the formatting for you (converting `0.1` to `10%`).

Comment: i already format it as percentage but in Kaizala it show number not Percentage